# How to control expandable v-data-table expand icon's position?

Tags: vuetify.js

[image]

From [vuetify'e example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#expandable-rows), the icon shows up at right side of each row.
[image]

But when I making my own, the arrow showed up at the left side, I havent figured out how to control its position.

My code is like following

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="inputs"
  item-key="id"
  disable-pagination
  dense
  show-expand
  single-expand
  hide-default-footer
>
  <template v-slot:[`item.value`]="{ item }">
    <v-progress-linear
      height="22"
      ></v-progress-linear
    >
  </template>
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{headers, item}">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">
      <InputDetails
        :input="item"
      />
    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Added one more header into header list did the magic. { text: '', value: 'data-table-expand' },

Comment: You just made my day!